# AngularJS / express : OPTIONS request not sent with header

Tags: angularjs, express

I have two routes on my `express` server:

- One is public that returns a token and works great
- The other one is protected and we pass through a middleware that checks if the `x-access-token` header is set.

With postman everything works fine.

But, with AngularJS 1.6, even with the interceptor, the request is sent without the header.

So, when the OPTIONS verb is invoked before the POST, it fails as the header is not present in the OPTIONS request.

---

Question : How can I tell AngularJS to put the header for the OPTIONS request ?

PS: In my express middleware I can may be put something like :

```
if (request.method === 'OPTIONS')
   return response.status(200)
```

but not sure if it's the correct way ...

Comment: This is not about Angular JS - this is how browser send cross-domain requests. Yes, you need to add valid 'OPTIONS' endpoint on your server.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov Thank you for your response. I know that this the preflight mecanism. But I'm still not sure why should I treat it manually ? Why AngularJS is not able to catch a request that he fired ?

Comment: This is fired by browser, not angular.

Comment: I know ... this the problem : the interceptor is pushed into the httpProvider ...  the other requests (ex: browser) are not detected.